# Adding array to variables in Loop in MASM

Tags: loops, assembly, masm, masm32

I am trying to write a loop where I add an Array `array SWORD 1000h, 2000h, 3000h, 4000h` to some variables `num1  BYTE 1 num2  BYTE 2 num3  BYTE 4 num4  BYTE 8 total BYTE ?` and store the summation to the variable (example num1 = 1000h + num1).

I'm having trouble getting the loop running as I am new to assembly and I seeming to be approaching it the wrong way compared to something I'd do in python. I mainly want some guidance on the loop and what I am doing wrong.

```
.386

.model flat, stdcall

.stack 4096

ExitProcess PROTO dwExitCode:DWORD

.data
array SWORD 1000h, 2000h, 3000h, 4000h
num1  BYTE 1
num2  BYTE 2
num3  BYTE 4
num4  BYTE 8
total BYTE ?

.code
main PROC

    mov edi,OFFSET array    ; assigning array address to edi
    mov ecx,LENGTHOF array  ; loop counter
    mov eax, 0              ; sum = 0
L1:
    add eax,[edi]           ;add interger
    add edi,TYPE array      ;points to next array element
    loop L1                 ;repeat until ECX is 0

    ;mov eax num3
    ;add eax num4
    ;mov (num3 + num4)
    
    ;mov eax num1
    ;add eax num2
    ;mov (num1 + num2)
    ;mov total, eax

    INVOKE ExitProcess, 0

main ENDP
END main
```

For reference I have an Assignment in assembly using MASM x86 in visual studios.

[Assignment Details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/25Fyw.png)

Comment: `num1 = 1000h + num1` That obvisouly will not work since you've declared `num1` as a `BYTE`, which can't hold any values greater than `FFh`.

Comment: I think my professor wants me to override it using ```PTR``` but would it be better if I change it to a different value? I would still have to use ```PTR``` so I cant change it to an ```SWORD```